# Sending email with cakePHP3 Gourmet plugin

Tags: php, email, cakephp-3.0

I'm using [Gourmet/email](https://github.com/gourmet/email) plugin to send email in CakePHP3. But I've remarked that the mail is displaying `Email/html` heading.

My email template is as follow :

```
Bonjour <?= $user['prenom'] ?> <br/>

Veuillez confirmer la création de votre compte en suivant ce lien : <br /><br />

<a href="<?= $this->Url->build(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'confirmaccount', '?' => ['email' => $user['email'], 'hash' => $hash]], true) ?>">Confirmer mon compte mandealR</a> <br />

Au cas où vous ne parvenez pas à cliquer sur le lien, merci de vouloir copier l'adresse suivante et la coller dans votre navigateur : <br /><br />

<br />
<?= $this->Url->build(['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'confirmaccount', '?' => ['email' => $user['email'], 'hash' => $hash]], true) ?> <br /> <br />

Merci de nous avoir choisi, <br /><br />

L'équipe mandealR, <br /><br />

<?= $this->Html->image('img/mr_logo.png', ['fullBase' => TRUE]) ?>
```

And in the controller action :

```
$email = new Email();
            $email->to($user->email);
            $email->subject('Confirmation de la création de votre compte');
            $email->emailFormat('html');
            $email->template('welcome');
            $email->viewVars(['user' => ['prenom' => $user->prenom, 'email' => $user->email], 'hash' => $hash]);
            $email->send();
```

[image]

What's going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default title based on the (layout) view template path. It is used in your/the plugins default layout template.

- **[https://github.com/gourmet/email/...3.1.1/src/Template/Layout/Email/html/default.ctp#L9](https://github.com/gourmet/email/blob/v3.1.1/src/Template/Layout/Email/html/default.ctp#L9)**
- **[https://github.com/gourmet/email/...3.1.1/src/Template/Layout/Email/html/default.ctp#L187](https://github.com/gourmet/email/blob/v3.1.1/src/Template/Layout/Email/html/default.ctp#L187)**

This isn't unique to the plugin, it's how the CakePHP view class generally works, it sets this default value for the `title` block in case it isn't defined yet, or empty.

If you want to change the title, you can for example easily overwrite/set the block content in your your view templates.

```
$this->assign('title', 'Some title...');
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Layouts](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#layouts)**

Comment: Thanks @ndm for your answer. I've found [this other plugin](https://github.com/OraInteractive/CakePHP3-Email-Template) that seems interesting.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody needs an email plugin supporting html and css, [this link](https://github.com/OraInteractive/CakePHP3-Email-Template) can be useful.